# I have changed the Firebase name in my app but still the app loads the old firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I change all the setting to my own settings.
the firebase settings is my own.

```
"firebase_url": "https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
```

I rebuild the app in android studio, the build apk.
uppload it to my phone, when i then try it, it still have the old firebase in the app.
I dont now what to do, and hope someone can help me.

**Uppdate:**

Can it be something in the package names?
This is the name i have.

**root/app/build.gradle**

```
applicationId: com.xxxxxxx.user.app
```

**root/app/src/main/AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxxxxx.app">
```

**Root/app/google-services.json**

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "firebase_url": "https://xxxxxxx-user.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "xxxxxxx-user",
    "storage_bucket": "xxxxxxx-user.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.xxxxxx.user.app"
        }
      },
```

**Firebase Console:**

```
Project name : xxxxxxx-user
Project ID : xxxxxxx-user
```

**root/app/src/main/java/com/xxxxxxx/user/app/Helper**

```
package com.xxxxxxx.user.app.Helper;
```

Comment: The application you have will connect to FireBase based on the file you placed in the root (Root/app/google-services.json) regardless of the application name on your machine and its name on FireBase.
So be sure to replace the file that links the application to the correct Firebas project.

Comment: But thats the problem. It doesent connect. I cant add anything in firebase. . It connect to anather firebase thats not in google-services.. And i cant find the link in the project..

Answer (score 0):

make sure to create new google-services.json in firebase, or delete the one already in your project root folder.

From the Firebase Console:

1. Simply log in to the console
2. Choose the project the app is connected to
3. You will see a box displaying information about the Android App
   connected to the Firebase project
4. Click on the 3 dots button at the top right of the android app box
   and click Manage
5. Scroll down a bit and click the arrow button next to the Advanced
   Options header
6. A Delete this app button will appear, click it and it will
   disconnect your android app from your Firebase project.

Comment: I have already done that, still have the old firebase lik, NOT mine.

Comment: it doesent work, genereate a new google-service.json nd it doesent work...